# Expected input to be one of these types: char Instead its type was struct

Tags: matlab

I have been given assistance on this code, but there seems to be an error when compiling the code.

```
function search;

Videoinfo = dir('*videotest.avi');

File = {Videoinfo};

nfiles = length(File);

if nfiles == 0
  error('No avi files available in this directory');
end
for objnum = 1 : nfiles
  videoobjs(objnum) = VideoReader(File{objnum});
end
outobj = VideoWriter('newvideo.avi');
open(outobj);

while true
  someleft = arrayfun(@hasFrame, videoobjs);

  if ~all(someleft); break; end

  for objnum = 1 : nfiles

     thisframe(:,:,:,objnum) = readFrame(videoobjs(objnum));

     meanframe = mean(thisframe, 4);

     writeVideo(outobj, meanframe);

   end

 end

close(outobj);

for objnum = 1 : nfiles
  close(videoobjs(objnum));
end
end
```

The following error keeps appearing when running the program:

```
"Expected input to be one of these types:
char
Instead its type was struct."
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: the thread is here for the help https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/273516-no-avi-files-available

Comment: Run your code step by step using the debugger and check the data structure. `dir` returns a struct, not a list. This ends up `File{objnum}` being not a file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue is because the variable, `VideoInfo` (returned from `dir`) is a `struct` *not* a cell array of strings. Because of this, you will need to reference the `name` field of the resulting `struct` to access the filename.

The easiest option (and what seems to be what you wanted) would be to set `File` to a list of all of the filenames

```
% This will create a cell array of all filenames. NOTE the use of the NAME field
File = {Videoinfo.name};

% Then later
videoobjs(objnum) = VideoReader(File{objnum});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and removed the error but another error appeared unfortunately.                                                                     Unable to determine the codec required.

Error in VideoReader (line 172)
            obj.init(fileName);

Error in search (line 11)
  videoobjs(objnum) = VideoReader(File{objnum});                                                         This is confusing me because Matlab should have all the codecs when downloading the software, unless .avi is not an acceptable format anymore

Comment: @AndrewCardozo That is something specific to the `VideoReader` and your machine. As a note though, AVI is a *container* format and really the video can be encoded in one of many ways *within* the AVI so just because it's an AVI doesn't mean that it will work. [More info here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-video-file-formats.html). If you're still having issues, a new question is likely appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I might post a new question about this if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @AndrewCardozo not a problem. Be sure to check out that documentation page I linked and check what format your file actually is prior to starting a new question. You may be able to figure it out

Comment: I did read the link you sent, and unfortunately the avi format that I am trying to read is a dvsd codec which apparently was removed in 2004.

Comment: @AndrewCardozo maybe checkout [handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) to convert formats?

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you with questions, I just have one more problem if you could help. The error reads "Frames of type double must be in the range 0 to 1.  writeVideo(outobj,meanframe);

Comment: Your suggestion for converting the files helped alot, thanks for the advice

Comment: @AndrewCardozo it expects the the data to be normalized. You will likely need to divide `meanframe` by the max of `meanframe` to normalize it.

Comment: I used the code  c= rdivide(meanframe,max(meanframe));

Comment: is that what you are talking about